# Ng-repeat one-time binding and "track by" change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular1.6, angularjs-track-by, one-time-binding

Our web app uses ngRepeat to display a list of items. The array and its objects are never changed, but values of the objects inside can be modified by the user.

We generate a unique trackId's for each item. This trackId is updated every time the item's values change.

We are also using the one-time binding syntax to reduce the number of watchers on the page (as it can quickly climb to the thousands).

However, this combination does not seem to actually work; If the item's trackId changes but the object's reference stays the same, the item is *not* re-rendered.

From the angularJS docs:

> Custom Expression: It is possible to use any AngularJS expression to
>   compute the tracking id, for example with a function, or using a
>   property on the collection items. item in items track by item.id is a
>   typical pattern when the items have a unique identifier, e.g. database
>   id. **In this case the object identity does not matter. Two objects are
>   considered equivalent as long as their id property is same.** Tracking
>   by unique identifier is the most performant way and should be used
>   whenever possible.

If this is the case, why is the item not destroyed and re-created when the trackId is modified?

For example:

```
$scope.friends = [
    {name:'John', age:25, id: 'John-25'},
    {name:'Mary', age:40, id: 'Mary-40'},
    {name:'Peter', age:85, id: 'Peter-85'}
];

$scope.change = function(i) {
    var f = $scope.friends[i];
    f.age = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    f.id = f.name + '-' + f.age;
};
```

And

```
 <div ng-repeat="friend in friends track by friend.id">
    <div ng-bind="'Track id: ' + friend.id"></div>
    <div ng-bind="'Regular binding:' + friend.age"></div>
    <div ng-bind="::'One-time binding:' + friend.age"></div>
</div>

<button ng-click="change(0)">Change John's age</button>
<button ng-click="change(1)">Change Marys's age</button>
<button ng-click="change(2)">Change Peters's age</button>
```

In this demo I would expect the object to be destroyed when the trackId changes and the element should be re-rendered with the new one-time binding value.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Lklq3ZNDUuggjgwmkoxj?p=preview

Does anyone have any suggestions on a way to get around this? We absolutely cannot remove one-time binding for performance reasons. I have also looked into angular-bind-notifier but that will require every binding in the repeat to be updated since it cannot target specific rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `id` on each `friend` constant.

If this `id` is truly just an ID for each friend, why would it need to change?  If you're using that property for something *more* than an ID, maybe consider adding a new property on the object and keep the ID's constant.

If you don't want to do that, you could always create some helper function that stores a current friend's `id-value` in a dictionary with `id` keys.  Then, you can just update or retrieve the value stored in that friend ID by `friend.id`.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` is using `$watchCollection` internally which is a shallow watch on the array, so changing a property on one of the array items wont cause the `ng-repeat` to update. The docs are a bit misleading here.

As you guessed you need to change the object reference. After toggling the id replace the object with a shallow copy. This will will cause `$watchCollection` to detect the change and `ng-repeat` will then replace the item due to the `id` change.

```
$scope.friends = [
    {name:'John', age:25, id: 'John-25'},
    {name:'Mary', age:40, id: 'Mary-40'},
    {name:'Peter', age:85, id: 'Peter-85'}
];

$scope.change = function(i) {
    var f = $scope.friends[i];
    f.age = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    f.id = f.name + '-' + f.age;

    $scope.friends[i] = Object.assign({}, $scope.friends[i]);
};
```

Updated plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/s2ztGQ?p=preview